# C# - UpdateResource - To Remove A Resource

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I am able to successfully add a resource to a file using UpdateResource and then remove it using: UpdateResource(HANDLE, "TYPE", "NUMER", 1033, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
When I add a resource to the file it will add another even though there is an existing resource exactly the same, also I cannot remove any existing resources. When I try to remove an existing resource using that line I get the error ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you use

BeginUpdateResource(path, **true**);

then UpdateResource will replace the existing resource, but it will delete everything on the current resource not only the "TYPE" you use in UpdateResource.